# Why is "More Data Better than Less Data"?

Tags: probability, statistics, convergence-divergence

According to Wikipedia:

- The Fisher Information is a way of measuring the amount of information that an observable random variable X carries about an unknown parameter θ of a distribution that models X. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information)
- The Central Limit Theorem states that when independent random variables are summed up, their properly normalized sum tends toward a normal distribution even if the original variables themselves are not normally distributed. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem)

I thought of the following experiment: Suppose we generate a single random number from a normal distribution (with a specific mean and specific standard deviation), we then take the difference of this single number and the mean of the normal distribution. We then generate two random numbers from the same normal distribution, take the mean of these two random numbers and subtract them from the mean of the normal distribution. We keep repeating the process again and again (e.g. 500 times). I demonstrate this using the R programming language:

```
results <- list()
for (i in 1:500) {

    iteration = i
    number_i_1 = mean(rnorm(i,10,2))
    difference_i_1 = 10 - number_i_1
 
    results_tmp = data.frame(iteration, difference_i_1)

    results[[i]] <- results_tmp
}

results_df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, results)

head(results_df)
  iteration difference_i_1
1         1     0.39698934
2         2    -0.30624098
3         3     2.56744178
4         4    -1.62484572
5         5     0.45499738
6         6    -0.01635959

plot(results_df$iteration, results_df$difference_i_1, type = "b",
     xlab = "Number of Points", ylab = "Difference in Averages", main = "Difference Between Random Numbers and Mean for a Normal Distribution")
```

[image]

I can now repeat this experiment with the Exponential Distribution (I wonder if in theory, the rates of "convergence" for these graphs might be different):

```
results <- list()
for (i in 1:500) {

    iteration = i
    number_i_1 = mean(rexp(i,10))
    difference_i_1 = 10 - number_i_1

    results_tmp = data.frame(iteration, difference_i_1)

    results[[i]] <- results_tmp
}

results_df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, results)

plot(results_df$iteration, results_df$difference_i_1, type = "b",
     xlab = "Number of Points", ylab = "Difference in Averages", main = "Difference Between Random Numbers and Mean for a Exponential  Distribution")
```

[image]

**My Question:** In both of these cases, we can see that both graphs eventually approach 0 as the number of points increase - in this experiment, "more data appears to be better than less data". I am trying to understand the following point : **Are the behaviors of these graphs explained by "Fisher's Information" (i.e. the amount of information a random variable carries about its distribution) - or are these behaviors better explained using the "Central Limit Theorem"?**

Thanks!

Comment: This belongs on CrossValidated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviours of these graphs are just explained by [The Law of Large Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers), i.e. you are just observing:
\begin{align}
 \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i - \mu \stackrel{\mathbb{P}}{\rightarrow} 0
\end{align}

because $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = \mu \: \forall \: i$. It is misleading to say that this is a consequence of the Central Limit Theorem, because the Law of Large Numbers may hold even if the Central Limit Theorem does not. The Fisher Information has nothing to do with what you observe.

In other words and more generally, if you have a **consistent** estimator sequence (i.e. satisfying the display above), it is not granted that this estimator sequence will also have a limiting normal behavior as stated in the Central Limit Theorem (see for instance the case of estimator sequences with infinite variance).

Answer (score 0):

"More data is better than less data" is vague. It usually means that we can get better estimation of something if we have more data points (of course adding data can never worsen the situation, as we can just discard extra points).

Convergence of your graphs to $0$ is consequence of [Law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers). Which is a consequence of Central Limit Theorem, but also applicable to some distributions that doesn't obey it. Yes, rate of convergence can be different, and for some distributions sample mean doesn't convert at all - for example, for [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution) the sample mean has the same distribution as the terms.

Fischer information has nothing to do with all of it.